# Passive FTP that would work inside and outside of NAT

Tags: nat, ftp

I'm using vsftpd 2.2.2 behind the NAT.

To make it work, I set `pasv_address` to my external (internet) IP. Now the problem is with clients that connect it through the LAN - they try to connect to the passive IP advertised by server and obviously fail.

I know that some ftp clients can be configured to ignore the advertised address, but not all of them unfortunately.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

There some alternative solutions:

1. If possible in vsftpd, use different config for LAN and other. May be two different instance of vsftp.
2. Add src-nat for dst-nat connections on router internal ip
3. Use for server different from internal clients IP subnet.

PS. I quickly look at vsftpd config manual. It not possible to use different configuration for different client IP.

Comment: Can you hint how to provide two configs to `vsftpd`? two instances of `vsftpd` does not sound like a good option.

Comment: I quickly look at vsftpd config manual. It not possible to use different configuration for different client IP. Use option 2. or 3.

Comment: Unfortunately my server runs on AWS EC2. So I do not have access to NAT rules. The only doable option is to try using the Route53 service to implement split DNS technique.